# How to pass data containing special characters through curl

Tags: php, curl

### I cannot able to post data its contain the special characters through curl ,Any solution ?

first code is my curl function ,second code is my data need to pass

```
$communication_data_string = 'token='.json_encode(array(
    "activityTypeId"=>12,
    "activityId"=>5,
    "userID"=> 10,
    "partyID"=>20,
    "message_area_name"=>("this is my test data with special cheractors&&!@##$%$%%*)++")
    )
); 

echo(datPostingCURL($url, $communication_data_string));
```

?>

this seems to not returning anything if the messageData contains the special character's

Comment: can you give the $data_string?

Comment: {"message_area_name":"hai ..this is my test data .!@##$%$%%*)++"}

Comment: you should encode the special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code. I tested it in my local system. In my www director I created a folder named "test" for keeping the code. Then I created 2 files in that "test" folder. One file for sending the request and one for processing the request.

#### 1. curl.php

```
<?php
function datPostingCURL($url, $data_string)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
}
$url = "http://localhost/test/curl_post.php";

$communication_data_string = 'token='.json_encode(array(
    "activityTypeId"=>12,
    "activityId"=>5,
    "userID"=> 10,
    "partyID"=>20,
    "message_area_name"=>base64_encode("hai ..this is my test data .!@##$%$%%*)++")
    )
); 

echo(datPostingCURL($url, $communication_data_string));
?>
```

#### 2. curl_post.php

```
<?php
 print_r(json_decode($_POST['token']));

 $details = json_decode($_POST['token']); var_dump($details);
 echo base64_decode($details->message_area_name);
?>
```

**Note :**  While using special characters you should encode that string. I tried to convert it with `htmlspecialchars()`. But it didn't worked. So I used `base64` encoding method here.

Comment: $details=json_decode($details);
$message_area_name=$details->message_area_name; when i am fetching the message_area_name as above it wont return anything,because of the special characters in the data

Answer (score 2):

Try [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

or

How about using the entity codes...

```
@ = %40

& = %26
```

Answer (score 2):

change the line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($data_string));
```

the receive it in following way as you are not using any specific post variable

```
$data = urldecode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```